# Why not Android MediaPlayer provide getDataSource API?

Tags: android, android-mediaplayer

Is there any considerations why Android MediaPlayer doesn't provide getDataSource API?

What's more, can two MediaPlayer objects play the same file at the same time?

Comment: and what `getDataSource API` would return? `String`? `Uri`? `FileDescriptor`? `MediaDataSource`?

Comment: I might assume that there may be some DRM issues if MediaPlayer provides getDataSource. However, it would be useful as the MediaDataSource interface, which would be returned, would implement a readAt method giving access to the audio data itself. However, that opens a new can of worms given the plethora of media formats.

Answer (score 1):

That's probably just a design desition because some parts of MediaPlayer is in native code and implementation of getDataSource would be a bit tricky.

You can easily play the same file in two MediaPlayers, just manage it yourself.

```
    mediaPlayer.reset()
    mediaPlayer.setAudioStreamType(AudioManager.STREAM_MUSIC)

    mediaPlayer2.reset()
    mediaPlayer2.setAudioStreamType(AudioManager.STREAM_MUSIC)

    context.resources.openRawResourceFd(R.raw.audio_file)
            .use { assetFileDescriptor ->
                mediaPlayer.setDataSource(assetFileDescriptor.fileDescriptor,
                            assetFileDescriptor.startOffset, assetFileDescriptor.length)

                mediaPlayer.prepareAsync()

                mediaPlayer.setOnPreparedListener {
                    it.start()
                }

                mediaPlayer2.setDataSource(assetFileDescriptor.fileDescriptor,
                            assetFileDescriptor.startOffset, assetFileDescriptor.length)

                mediaPlayer2.prepareAsync()

                mediaPlayer2.setOnPreparedListener {
                    it.start()
                }
            }
```